# Spring Boot Not calling service layer in UAT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My spring Boot application is working fine in the local system. When Deployed in UAT, it is not calling service layer, getting nullpointerException

In my view (SubmissionView.java) I am calling

```
 List<Employee> employeeList = TouchKitHRUI.getEmployeeService().findAll();
```

In `TouchKitHRUI.java`
    Service layer is injected

```
 @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

calling service layer


public static EmployeeServiceImpl getEmployeeService() {

        return (EmployeeServiceImpl) ((TouchKitHRUI) getCurrent()).employeeService;
    }
```

Inside EmployeeServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {



@Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {

        logger.error("inside employee service impl");
        if(employeeRepo.findAll() != null)
                return (List<Employee>) employeeRepo.findAll();
            else
                return (new ArrayList());
    }
```

In UAT I am getting null pointer exception . It is not calling service layer .

How to solve this .

Here is my code

View

```
public class SubmissionView extends NavigationView {
    /**
     * 
     */

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8096272380114633426L;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SubmissionView.class);

    public SubmissionView() {
        setCaption("Submission");

    }

    protected void onBecomingVisible() {
        try {
            super.onBecomingVisible();

            class MyForm extends CssLayout implements Button.ClickListener {

                final ListSelect cboEmployeeID = new ListSelect("Employee ID");

                final TextField txtTitle = new TextField("Job Title");
                final TextField txtName = new TextField("Name");

                final DatePicker dateField = new DatePicker("Date");
                final TextField txtProjectCode = new TextField("Project Code");
                final TextArea textAreaDesc = new TextArea("Description of Project Code");
                NumberField numberTimeSpent = new NumberField("Time Spent(in Hours)");

                FieldGroup binder;



                public MyForm(Item item) {

                    logger.error("step-1**"); logger.error("..........start 000000");
                    numberTimeSpent.setConverter(Double.class);
                    logger.error("..........start 2");
                    VerticalComponentGroup group = new VerticalComponentGroup();
                    logger.error("..........start 3");
                    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
                    logger.error("..........start 4");
                    cboEmployeeID.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator("Please enter valid employee ID"));
                    logger.error("..........start 5");
                    cboEmployeeID.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
                    cboEmployeeID.setHeight("50%");
                    cboEmployeeID.setStyleName("v-select-select");
                    cboEmployeeID.setSizeFull();
                    cboEmployeeID.setRequired(true);

                    logger.error("before emplist ...");


                    List<Employee> employeeList = TouchKitHRUI.getEmployeeService().findAll();
                    logger.debug("step-2**"+employeeList);
                    //employeeList = TouchKitHRUI.getEmployeeService().findAll();
                    logger.debug("step-3**");
                    cboEmployeeID.addItems("Choose...");
                    List<String> empIDList = employeeList.stream().map(Employee::getEmpCode)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    cboEmployeeID.addItems(empIDList);
                    formLayout.addComponent(cboEmployeeID);

                    txtTitle.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator("Please enter title"));
                    txtTitle.setSizeFull();
                    txtTitle.setInputPrompt("Please enter title");
                    txtTitle.setRequired(true);
                    formLayout.addComponent(txtTitle);

                    txtName.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator("Please enter name"));
                    txtName.setSizeFull();
                    txtName.setInputPrompt("Please enter name");
                    txtName.setRequired(true);
                    formLayout.addComponent(txtName);
                    logger.debug("step-4**");
                    cboEmployeeID.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
                        Employee emp = TouchKitHRUI.getEmployeeService()
                                .findbyEmpCode(cboEmployeeID.getValue().toString());

                        logger.debug("step-5**");
                        if (emp != null) {
                            txtName.setValue(emp.getName());
                            txtTitle.setValue(emp.getEmpTitle());
                        }

                    });

                    dateField.setRequired(true);
                    dateField.setSizeFull();
                    formLayout.addComponent(dateField);

                    txtProjectCode.addValidator(
                            new StringLengthValidator("Please enter valid project code. (eg. P2018-GI-999)"));
                    txtProjectCode.setSizeFull();
                    txtProjectCode.setInputPrompt("Please enter project code");
                    txtProjectCode.setRequired(true);
                    formLayout.addComponent(txtProjectCode);

                    textAreaDesc.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator("Please enter description"));
                    textAreaDesc.setSizeFull();
                    textAreaDesc.setInputPrompt("Enter project description");
                    formLayout.addComponent(textAreaDesc);

                    numberTimeSpent.addValidator(new DoubleRangeValidator("Outside range", 1.0, 1000.0));
                    numberTimeSpent.setSizeFull();
                    numberTimeSpent.setRequired(true);
                    numberTimeSpent.setRequiredError("Enter time spent in hours");
                    formLayout.addComponent(numberTimeSpent);

                    group.addComponent(formLayout);
                    addComponent(group);

                    // Bind the form
                    binder = new FieldGroup(item);
                    binder.bindMemberFields(this);

                    // Handle the form
                    Button commit = new Button("Submit", this);
                    addComponent(commit);
                }

                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    try {

                        binder.commit();

                        TimeSheet timeSheet = new TimeSheet(cboEmployeeID.getValue().toString(),
                                txtTitle.getValue().toString(), txtName.getValue(), dateField.getValue(),
                                txtProjectCode.getValue().toString(), textAreaDesc.getValue(),
                                Double.parseDouble(numberTimeSpent.getValue()));
                         TouchKitHRUI.getTimeSheetService().save(timeSheet);

                        txtName.setValue("");
                        dateField.setValue(new Date());
                        textAreaDesc.setValue("");
                        numberTimeSpent.setValue("0.0");

                        Notification.show("" + "Submitted successfully.", Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);

                    } catch (CommitException e) {

                        Notification.show("Invalid value");
                    }
                }
            }

            Item item = new PropertysetItem();
            item.addItemProperty("cboEmployeeID", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
            item.addItemProperty("cboTitle", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
            item.addItemProperty("txtName", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
            item.addItemProperty("dateField", new ObjectProperty<Date>(new Date()));
            item.addItemProperty("cboProjectCode", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
            item.addItemProperty("textAreaDesc", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
            item.addItemProperty("numberTimeSpent", new ObjectProperty<Double>(0.0));

            MyForm form = new MyForm(item);
            setContent(form);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.toString()); logger.error(ex.toString());
            logger.error("Error");
            logger.error("Here is the error"+ex.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

TouchKitHRUI.java

```
/**
 * The UI's "main" class
 */
//@SuppressWarnings("serial")

// Use the TouchKit widget set for the TouchKit UI
@Widgetset("com.geomotion.hr.gwt.TouchKitSamplerWidgetSet")

// Use a custom theme
@Theme("mobiletheme")

// Cache static application files so as the application can be started
// and run even when the network is down.
@CacheManifestEnabled

// Switch to the OfflineMode client UI when the server is unreachable
@OfflineModeEnabled

// Make the server retain UI state whenever the browser reloads the app
@PreserveOnRefresh
@SpringUI(path = TouchKitHRUI.APP_ROOT)
public class TouchKitHRUI extends UI {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7416079964703904927L;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TouchKitHRUI.class);
    public static final String APP_ROOT = "/hrapp";

    // TODO This is currently unused in the sampler
    private final TouchKitHRPersistToServerRpc serverRpc = new TouchKitHRPersistToServerRpc() {
        @Override
        public void persistToServer() {
            // TODO this method is called from client side to store offline data
        }
    };

    @Autowired
    private TimeSheetService timeSheetService;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;



    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        TabBarView tabBarView = new TabBarView();

        final NavigationManager manager = new NavigationManager(new MainView());
        manager.addNavigationListener(new NavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public void navigate(NavigationEvent event) {
                if (event.getDirection() == NavigationEvent.Direction.BACK) {
                    // Do something
                    Notification.show("You came back to " + manager.getCurrentComponent().getCaption());
                }
            }
        });

        Tab tab1 = tabBarView.addTab(manager, "Main");
        tab1.setIcon(FontAwesome.LIST);

        setContent(tabBarView);

        // Use of the OfflineMode connector is optional
        OfflineMode offlineMode = new OfflineMode();
        offlineMode.extend(this);

        // Maintain the session when the browser application closes
        offlineMode.setPersistentSessionCookie(true);

        // Define the timeout in seconds to wait when a server
        // request is sent before falling back to offline mode
        offlineMode.setOfflineModeTimeout(15);



    }

    public static TimeSheetServiceImpl getTimeSheetService() {

        System.out.println("getTimeSheetService");
        return (TimeSheetServiceImpl) ((TouchKitHRUI) getCurrent()).timeSheetService;
    }

    public static ProjectServiceImpl getProjectService() {
        return (ProjectServiceImpl) ((TouchKitHRUI) getCurrent()).projectService;
    }

    public static EmployeeServiceImpl getEmployeeService() {

        logger.error("EmployeeService........");
        return (EmployeeServiceImpl) ((TouchKitHRUI) getCurrent()).employeeService;
    }}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl .java

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EmployeeServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

    @Override
    public Employee save(Employee employee) {
            return employeeRepo.save(employee);
    } 

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        return employeeRepo.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {

        logger.error("inside employee service impl");
        if(employeeRepo.findAll() != null)
                return (List<Employee>) employeeRepo.findAll();
            else
                return (new ArrayList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllActiveEmployee(boolean flag) {
        if(employeeRepo.findByIsActive(flag) != null)
            return (List<Employee>) employeeRepo.findByIsActive(flag);
        else
            return (new ArrayList());
    }

    @Override
    public Employee  findbyEmpCode(String empCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return employeeRepo.findByEmpCode(empCode);
    }


}
```

Comment: could you share the stack-trace?

Comment: There is no error .     Below from log file :                                                                                 
 2018-08-26 20:24:52.112 ERROR 4364 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.geomotion.hr.ui.SubmissionView       : java.lang.NullPointerException             I tried to print message  and found that problem in service layer . Not calling service layer .

Comment: Try running it in debug mode. possibly by running remote debug for the jar or so.